# CakePHP 3 - Bad render html when I want to generate a multiple checkbox field

Tags: cakephp, select, checkbox, cakephp-3.0

I've read [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-select-pickers) about cakephp 3 on this subject. I would like to create a multiple checkbox field but I've had a few problems in my view.

My view :

```
<?php
    $option = [
        'Value1' => '1',
        'Value2' => '2',
        'Value3' => '3'
    ];
?>
<?= $this->Form->create(null); ?>
<fieldset>
<legend><?= __('Catégories'); ?></legend>

<?= $this->Form->select('categ_list', $option, [
    'multiple' => 'checkbox',
]); ?>

</fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

The render :

[image]

Preview :

[image]

I don't know why cakephp generate this html code. I turned off BootstrapUI Plugin but the problem persists.

I use CakePHP v3 and I'm a begginer.

Thanks !

Comment: What do you expect your preview to look like ?

Comment: I would like to have only one column of checkbox.

Here `$this->Form->select()` provides me for each iteration of $option two `<label></label>` and two `<input type="checkbox">` nested.

Comment: Yes but where is your form creation code ? You should post it (`$this->Form->select()` I guess).

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problems by replacing

`$this->Form->select()`

by

`<?= $this->Form->input('categ_list', ['type' => 'select', 'options' => $option, 'multiple' => 'checkbox'])?>`

Thanks you